# BOOST TLS connection establishment using the boost after exchange of data between server and client

Tags: boost, boost-asio

I want to initiate the TLS connection only if the server supports the secure connection, to achieve this i have introduced the two message type between the server and client.

Client will send SECURECONNREQ msg to server after tcp connection establishment, if the server is configured to support the TLS it send SECURECONNRESP.

On receiving SECURECONNRESP the client will initiate the the TLS handshake by calling  boost asynhandshake API but this API is not sending the correct packet(client hello). In the wireshark i could see it is sending the protocol version as TLS1.1 even if it configured for TLS1.2.

Note: SSL context object is prepared with TLS1.2, ciphers and related certs.

It looks like the asynhandshake will not work properly if there is some data exchange happens on the TCP link.

Is there extra step we need take on BOOST asio to make it work?

**The secure connection establishment works perfectly fine with below implementation:**

Initiating the TLS connection without sending any data on the TCP link.

The client will initiate the TLS after connection is established(no data transfered on this link) by calling asynhandshake, the server will call boost asynhandshake immediately after the connnection accept.

Comment: "It looks like the asynhandshake will not work properly if there is some data exchange happens on the TCP link." - It looks like nothing here. We can't see the code, and we don't get any error reported. Maybe you should add a minimal reproducer.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard, or even impossible, to tell without seeing your actual code. But I thought it a nice challenge to write the quintessential PLAIN/TLS server/client in Asio, just to see whether there were any problems I might not have anticipated.

Sadly, it works. You may compare these and decide what you're doing differently.

If anything, this should help you create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to repro your issue.

### Short Intro

[image]

The server accepts connections.

The client initiates a `ConnectionRequest`. Depending on a runtime flag
`_support_tls` the server responds with the `SECURE` capability response (or not).

The client and server upgrade to TLS accordingly.

The client and server execute a very simple protocol session that's
templated on the Stream type, because the implementations are independent of
the transport layer security.

> Note, for the example I've used the `server.pem` from the Asio SSL examples.

The demo then executes servers both with and without SECURE capability, and
verifies that the same `simple_client` implementation works correctly
against both.

### Listing

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/endian/arithmetic.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace http = boost::beast::http;
namespace net  = boost::asio;
namespace ssl  = net::ssl;
using boost::system::error_code;
using net::ip::tcp;

struct ConnectionRequest {
    enum { MAGIC = 0x64fc };
    boost::endian::big_uint16_t magic = MAGIC;
};
struct ConnectionResponse {
    enum Capabilities {
        NONE,
        SECURE,
    };

    boost::endian::big_uint16_t capabilities = NONE;
};

using TLSStream = ssl::stream<tcp::socket>;

template <typename> static inline char const* stream_type = "(plain)";
template <> inline char const*                stream_type<TLSStream> = "(TLS)";

static void do_shutdown(tcp::socket& s) {
    error_code ignored;
    s.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ignored);
}

static void do_shutdown(TLSStream& s) {
    error_code ignored;
    s.shutdown(ignored);
}

template <typename Stream>
struct Session : std::enable_shared_from_this<Session<Stream> > {
    Session(Stream&& s) : _stream(std::move(s)) {}

    void start() {
        std::cout << "start" << type() << ": " << _stream.lowest_layer().remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
        http::async_read(_stream, _buf, _req, self_bind(&Session::on_request));
    }

  private:
    Stream _stream;
    
    http::request<http::string_body> _req;
    http::response<http::empty_body> _res;
    net::streambuf                   _buf;

    void on_request(error_code ec, size_t) {
        std::cout << "on_request" << type() << ": " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        http::async_write(_stream, _res, self_bind(&Session::on_response));
    }

    void on_response(error_code ec, size_t) {
        std::cout << "on_reponse" << type() << ": " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        do_shutdown(_stream);
    }

    auto type() const { return stream_type<Stream>; }

    auto self_bind(auto member) {
        return [self=this->shared_from_this(), member](auto&&... args) {
            return (*self.*member)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        };
    }
};

struct Server {
    using Ctx = ssl::context;

    Server(auto executor, uint16_t port, bool support_tls)
        : _acceptor(executor, {{}, port}),
          _support_tls(support_tls)
    {
        if (_support_tls) {
            _ctx.set_password_callback(
                 [](size_t, Ctx::password_purpose) { return "test"; });
            _ctx.use_certificate_file("server.pem", Ctx::file_format::pem);
            _ctx.use_private_key_file("server.pem", Ctx::file_format::pem);
        }
        _acceptor.listen();
        accept_loop();
    }

    ~Server() {
        _acceptor.cancel();
    }

  private:
    void accept_loop() {
        _acceptor.async_accept(
            make_strand(_acceptor.get_executor()),
            [=, this](error_code ec, tcp::socket&& sock) {
                if (!ec)
                    accept_loop();
                else
                    return;

                // TODO not async for brevity of sample here
                ConnectionRequest req[1];
                read(sock, net::buffer(req));

                if (req->magic != ConnectionRequest::MAGIC) {
                    std::cerr << "Invalid ConnectionRequest" << std::endl;
                    return;
                }
                ConnectionResponse res[1]{{ConnectionResponse::NONE}};

                if (not _support_tls) {
                    write(sock, net::buffer(res));

                    std::make_shared<Session<tcp::socket>>(std::move(sock))
                        ->start();
                } else {
                    res->capabilities = ConnectionResponse::SECURE;
                    write(sock, net::buffer(res));

                    // and then do the handshake
                    TLSStream stream(std::move(sock), _ctx);
                    stream.handshake(TLSStream::handshake_type::server);

                    std::make_shared<Session<TLSStream>>(std::move(stream))
                        ->start();
                }
            });
    }

    tcp::acceptor _acceptor;
    Ctx           _ctx{Ctx::method::sslv23};
    bool          _support_tls;
};

// simplistic one-time request/response convo
template <typename Stream> void simple_conversation(Stream& stream) {
    http::write(stream, http::request<http::string_body>(
                http::verb::get, "/demo/api/v1/ping", 11,
                "hello world"));

    {
        http::response<http::string_body> res;
        net::streambuf                    buf;

        http::read(stream, buf, res);
        std::cout << "Received: " << res << std::endl;
    }
}

void simple_client(auto executor, uint16_t port) {
    // client also not async for brevity
    tcp::socket sock(executor);
    sock.connect({{}, port});

    ConnectionRequest req[1];
    write(sock, net::buffer(req));

    ConnectionResponse res[1];
    read(sock, net::buffer(res));

    std::cout << "ConnectionResponse: " << res->capabilities << std::endl;
    if (res->capabilities != ConnectionResponse::SECURE) {
        simple_conversation(sock);
    } else {
        std::cout << "Server supports TLS, upgrading" << std::endl;

        ssl::context ctx{ssl::context::method::sslv23};

        TLSStream    stream(std::move(sock), ctx);
        stream.handshake(TLSStream::handshake_type::client);
        simple_conversation(stream);
    }
}

int main() {
    net::thread_pool ctx;
    {
        Server plain(ctx.get_executor(), 7878, false);
        simple_client(ctx.get_executor(), 7878);
    }

    {
        Server tls(ctx.get_executor(), 7879, true);
        simple_client(ctx.get_executor(), 7879);
    }
    ctx.join();
}
```

Prints

```
ConnectionResponse: start(plain): 0
127.0.0.1:37924
on_request(plain): Success
on_reponse(plain): Success
Received: HTTP/1.1 200 OK


ConnectionResponse: 1
Server supports TLS, upgrading
start(TLS): 127.0.0.1:36562
on_request(TLS): Success
on_reponse(TLS): Success
Received: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Comment: Accidentally posted the version with handshake type reversed. [Fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66863212/revisions) to be more sensible

Comment: Thank u very much for ur reply , i have  asynchronous mode of communication in my application. we have used asynchandshake method.

Comment: On client side i am calling asynhandshake immediately after sending the SECURECONNREQ msg to server. It looks like server failed to differentiate the normal data(SECURECONNREQ) and client hello data, so server not initiating the TLS.

Comment: That would only happen if you don't have fixed-size reads and you accidentally ignore the data that is already in the buffer. This is a common bug with e.g. `read_until`: `read_until` promises that the match condition is met, it does **not** guarantee that no more bytes are read. So yeah, I would check that code. Because we cannot see it, I cannot comment. (Asiode, async_handshake really makes no difference - it obviously has the stream semantics).